# Names denoted the same entity

Tags: c++, scope, declaration

The following definition of *declarative region*:

> Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a
>   declarative region, which is the largest part of the program in which
>   that name is valid, that is, in which that name may be used as an
>   unqualified name to refer to the same entity.

We have example into the spec below:

```
int j = 24;
int main() {
    int i = j, j;
    j = 42;
}
```

> the identifier j is declared twice as a name (and used twice). The
>   declarative region of the first j includes the entire example. The
>   potential scope of the first j begins immediately after that j and
>   extends to the end of the program, but its (actual) scope excludes the
>   text between the , and the }. The declarative region of the second
>   declaration of j (the j immediately before the semicolon) includes all
>   the text between { and }, but its potential scope excludes the
>   declaration of i. The scope of the second declaration of j is the same
>   as its potential scope.

It's unclear how to determine declarative region for arbitrary name. At least I can't find this into the standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The potential scope of a variable declared at the file scope (i.e., not inside a namespace, class, or function) is from the point at which the variable is declared until the end of file. The potential scope of a variable declared inside a function is from the point at which the variable is declared until the close brace inside of which the variable was declared.

The actual scope of a variable can be smaller than the potential scope if a new variable of the same name is declared at some inner scope. This is called *shadowing*.

```
// The following introduces the file scope variable j.
// The potential scope for this variable is from here to the end of file.
int j = 42; 

// The following introduces the file scope variable k.
int k = 0;

// Note the parameter 'j'. This shadows the file scope 'j'.
void foo (int j) 
{
    std::cout << j << '\n'; // Prints the value of the passed argument.
    std::cout << k << '\n'; // Prints the value of the file scope k.
}
// The parameter j is out of scope. j once again refers to the file scope j.


void bar ()
{
    std::cout << j << '\n'; // Prints the value of the file scope j.
    std::cout << k << '\n'; // Prints the value of the file scope k.

    // Declare k at function variable, shadowing the file scope k.
    int k = 1; 
    std::cout << k << '\n'; // Prints the value of the function scope k.

    // This new k in the following for loop shadows the function scope k.
    for (int k = 0; k < j; ++k) { 
        std::cout << k << '\n'; // Prints the value of the loop scope k.
    }
    // Loop scope k is now out of scope. k now refers to the function scope k.

    std::cout << k << '\n'; // Prints the function scope k.
}
// Function scope k is out of scope. k now refers to the file scope k.
```

Comment: So what definition of declarative region?

Comment: The declarative region of a variable is the potential scope of that variable less the region where the variable is shadowed.

Comment: But in the N3797 draft 3.3/2 example implies that `The declarative region of the first j includes the entire example.`

Comment: `The declarative region of a variable is the potential scope of that variable less the region where the variable is shadowed.` It is not true because `Every name is introduced in some portion of program text called a declarative region, which is the largest part of the program in which that name is valid`

Comment: It most certainly is true. The unqualified variable name refers to a   different entity in a region where the variable is shadowed. You truncated a key part of the definition. Quoting, emphasis mine, "... the largest part of the program in which that name is valid, **that is, in which that name may be used as an unqualified name to refer to the same entity.**"

Comment: There's an easy way around this if you find the concept of shadowing confusing: Don't do it. There are lots of organizations that forbid shadowing in their coding standards. That said, there is one place where shadowing is widely used: In constructors. It's quite common to shadow a data member with an argument name and use that argument to provide an initial value for the data member with the same name.